# Decrypt RC4 in Linux

Tags: encryption

I'm looking to decrypt RC4 encrypted data. I've tried openssl but it doesn't support my key length of 64 bits (my version only has rc4 and rc4-40).

Encrypted data:
6dec8a6b6356b36e1f4c1a94c8f6dd5ddfd60108da479d5b4a8794afa468c7e78cd22946d7

Key: 
24641684

The plain text should come out to:
ThisIstheOriginaltext=theoriginaltext

Using this website http://rc4.online-domain-tools.com/ I am able to successfuly decrypt the data. However I am struggling to decrypt it in linux without the use of a website tool.

How can I decrypt this in linux?

Answer (score 2):

RC4? It should be easy. There is a very short c version that supports any key (hex encoded) length. Just compile like this:

```
$ gcc -o rc4 -O4 rc4.c
```

this code:

```
#define S ,t=s[i],s[i]=s[j],s[j]=t /* rc4 hexkey <file */
unsigned char k[256],s[256],i,j,t;main(c,v,e)char**v;{++v;while(++i)s[
i]=i;for(c=0;*(*v)++;k[c++]=e)sscanf((*v)++-1,"%2x",&e);while(j+=s[i]
+k[i%c]S,++i);for(j=0;c=~getchar();putchar(~c^s[t+=s[i]]))j+=s[++i]S;}
```

Usage is:

```
$ rc4 hexkey < input > output
```

Shamelessly copied from [this site](http://www.cypherspace.org/rsa/rc4c.html):

If you need/want the long version, [use this](http://www.cypherspace.org/rsa/rc4.html).
This one is more robust, just a little bigger as it is a 2k file of c code.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the `openssl` utility that comes with most Linux distributions wasn't compiled with support for `rc4-64`.

What you can do is grab the latest source code from the OpenSSL [website](http://www.openssl.org/source/) and compile it yourself.

Comment: Which version? openssl-1.0.1e only contains [EVPs](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP) `EVP_rc4()` and `EVP_rc4_40()`, no mention of an explicit 64-bit variant except in the `enc` man page, which I suspect might be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenSSL `enc` utility only supports *rc4* which is implicitly 128-bit by default (`EVP_rc4()`), and *rc4-40* (`EVP_rc4_40()`).

The former supports variable key sizes (via `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length()`) but it seems `enc` does not support non-default key sizes, and never calls that set-length function. I'm not aware of any CLI tool or perl module which supports this.

Instead, you can trivially amend the `do_crypt()` RC2 80-bit example in the OpenSSL `EVP_EncryptInit` man page to do RC4-64 (or any other supported size):

```
// compile with: gcc -lcrypto -o rc4-64 rc4-64.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    FILE *in,*out; 

    // encrypt
    //in=fopen("rc4.in","r");
    //out=fopen("rc4.out","w");
    //do_crypt(in,out,1);
    //fclose(in); 
    //fclose(out);

    // decrypt
    in=fopen("rc4.out","r");
    out=fopen("rc4.txt","w");
    do_crypt(in,out,0);
    fclose(in); 
    fclose(out);
}

int do_crypt(FILE *in, FILE *out, int do_encrypt)
{
    /* Allow enough space in output buffer for additional block */
    unsigned char inbuf[1024], outbuf[1024 + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH];
    int inlen, outlen;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;

    /* Bogus key and IV: we'd normally set these from
       * another source.  */
    //unsigned char key[] = "0123456789";
    //unsigned char iv[] = "12345678";
    unsigned char key[] = "24641684";
    unsigned char iv[] = "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";

    /* Don't set key or IV because we will modify the parameters */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);

    /* set RC4 with 64-bit key */
    EVP_CipherInit_ex(&ctx, EVP_rc4(), NULL, NULL, NULL, do_encrypt);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length(&ctx, 64/8)

    /* We finished modifying parameters so now we can set key and IV */

    EVP_CipherInit_ex(&ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv, do_encrypt);
    for(;;) {
        inlen = fread(inbuf, 1, 1024, in);
        if(inlen <= 0) break;
        if(!EVP_CipherUpdate(&ctx, outbuf, &outlen, inbuf, inlen)) {
            /* Error */
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
            return 0;
        }
        fwrite(outbuf, 1, outlen, out);
    }
    if(!EVP_CipherFinal_ex(&ctx, outbuf, &outlen)) {
        /* Error */
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
        return 0;
    }
    fwrite(outbuf, 1, outlen, out);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
    return 1;
}
```

(Error checking etc omitted for brevity and clarity - *this is not production code*)